# GSAP target undefined not found when using CSS Rule Plugin on React Site

Tags: css, reactjs, gsap

I am trying to use the GSAP CSS Rule Plugin to target and animate a pseudo selector. The problem is that it doesn't detect it and logs `GSAP target undefined not found` to the console. I tried to get the element by logging the element to the console but it is also undefined.

Here is how I am using it:

```
import { gsap } from "gsap"
import { CSSRulePlugin } from "gsap/CSSRulePlugin"

const IndexPage = () => {
  
  useEffect(() => {
    gsap.registerPlugin(CSSRulePlugin);
    const titleRule = CSSRulePlugin.getRule(
      "span.landing__title--span::after"
    )
    // Log titleRule
    console.log(titleRule). // undefined

    const tl = gsap.timeline();
    tl.to(
      titleRule,
      {
        cssRule: {
          scaleY: 0,
          duration: 1
        },
      }
    )
  },[])
  
  return (
    <div>
        <span className="landing__title--span">Hey there</span>
    </div>
  )
}

export default IndexPage
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I rectify it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found the reason it wasn't working.
When you use CSSRulePlugin, you have to be very specific about your selectors.

The selector you use in the getRule() heavily depends on the selector you use in your CSS (cause it will change this specific rule).

If in your CSS you're e.g. using `landing__title--span::after` and you reference `span.landing__title--span::after` in getRule(), it won't work. The selector in the getRule() has to be match with the selector in your css because that's what it wants to overwrite.

So in your css, if your style goes like this:

```
.landing__title--span::after {
  /*Yout styles*/
}
```

Your getRule has to be defined like this:

```
const titleRule = CSSRulePlugin.getRule(
  ".landing__title--span::after"
)
```

Comment: The exact same selector is needed because it's (near) impossible to generically find any selector that matches. As an alternative to using the CSSRulePlugin, you could instead animate CSS variables (which is generally the preferred method)

Comment: @ZachSaucier Thank you but how do I use css variables with a pseudo element like `::before` and `::after`

Comment: You use a variable for whatever properties you're trying to animate. Then animate those variables.